# Windows Registry access denied when administrator

Tags: windows, security, regedit

Windows 7 workstation, 
Launch '*`regedit.exe`*' as 'Administrator'

Find the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}
```

Right click and select 'Permissions'
Change owner to administrators group.
Change permissions for administrators group. Grant Full Control.
I get an error saying:

> unable to save permission, access denied

Why do get access denied when I run as administrator?

Comment: What is the UAC set for?

Comment: Are you on a domain? If so, the domain security settings may be restricting you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Administrator does not mean "you get all rights to do anything." Administrator happens to be an account (or in your case, most likely the Local Administrators group) which by default is given some sensitive privileges like `SeDebugPrivilege` and similar. However, as far as the security subsystem is concerned, it is just an account. (Very much unlike `root` in Unix-like operating systems) If you aren't the owner of the key in question, and your account does not have `WRITE_DAC` access to the registry key in question, then you won't be able to change the access control list on the key in question.

Try taking ownership first. By default, the local administrators group has `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege`, which allows taking ownership of any object even without the `WRITE_OWNER` permission being granted by the object's discretionary access control list. Once you are the owner, you should be implicitly granted `READ_CONTROL` (which allows you to read the security descriptor on the object in question), and `WRITE_DAC` (which allows you to write to the DACL on the key in question). (Assuming the `OWNER_RIGHTS` SID isn't in use; that's extremely unlikely)

Comment: Apologies for awakening a dead question, but how exactly do you "take ownership"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @newbiedoodle: Make a security descriptor with yourself as the owner (`InitializeSecurityDescriptor` / `SetSecurityDescriptorOwner`), and call `SetSecurityInfo` / `SetNamedSecurityInfo` or similar with it.

Comment: @newbie: Sorry, was responding as if it were a StackOverflow question. :) In the registry editor go to the security editor and click "Advanced" and owner is listed at the top.

Comment: @BillyONeal Eh, still got it. It took a little more Googling, but same thing. Thanks again.

Comment: Access denied on take ownership from admin account too.