# Why can't I change Window 7 registry key?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I want to change a Windows 7 Registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Classes->CLSID->B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8} -> InprocServer32`. I ran regedit as administrator. But when I was trying to modify that key, it doesn't allow me to change and reports error as

```
Cannot edit: error writing the value's new contents
```

So why can't I change the registry key even in administrator mode? How to solve this problem in Windows 7? I also disabled my Anti-Virus but it didn't help.

Comment: This is related to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/601543/postgresql-windows-installation-failure) that was originally on SO and was migrated to SU

Comment: in brief: admin right aren't enough, you must also get the ownership of the stuff you want to change. https://superuser.com/a/493121/235752

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because by default Administrators only have read permissions for that key

[image]

You can open the permissions window by right clicking on `InprocServer32` and choosing `Permissions...`.

Now to head off a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why are you wanting to changes the value in the first place?

Comment: Thanks. I originally posted a question related to Postgresql installation problem on SO and someone suggested me to post here. So this is related to that question.

Answer (score 0):

That key usually belongs to the VBS script handler DLL.  Symantec likes to overwrite it with their script scanning engine, and since you mentioned disabling your Anti Virus, I'm guessing you are using a Symantec AV product (but other AV packages may also do similar).

Even though you disabled the AV protection the package may still be actively preventing you from tampering with the keys.  Most likely to keep malware from modifying it.

Try modifying it while in booted in Safe Mode, or use `MSConfig` to disable all the Symantec services and utilities until you're done.

Depending on the issue, perhaps completely uninstall the Symantec package, and/or reinstall without the Script Scanning features (if possible).