# PostgreSQL Windows installation failure

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to install PostgreSQL 9.2 in Windows 7. When I launched the installer, it failed and showed the error message:

```
Unable to write inside TEMP environment variable path
```

I did a lot of research. I tried almost all methods but none of them works. Finally I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13927764/1649466).

I can see my `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Classes->CLSID->B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8} -> InprocServer32` is NOT `C:\Windows\System32\vbscript.dll`. It is incorrectly set to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore\ScriptSn.20120815030544.dll`. Actually I don't have McAfee installed on my machine.

But when I tried modifying this key, Windows regedit doesn't allow me to change this key.

So what can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to run your installer as an administrator. (Right-click the installer, and choose `Run as administrator` from the context menu.) Adminstrative privileges are required to write to `HKLM` on Vista and higher (or XP when not running as a power user or local administrator). Software installation isn't really a programming question; this is more suited for [su] instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried running PostgreSQL installer in administrator mode but the same error happened. I guess it is due to the incorrect Registry key. So how to run the regedit in administrator mode in Win 7 so that I can change that key?

Comment: Start it from an adminstrator command prompt. (Click the Start button and type `Command` in the search box. When `Command Prompt` appears at the top of the menu, right-click it and choose `Run as administrator`. Once that command prompt appears, type `regedit` and hit Enter.) Once again, not a programming question. :-)

Comment: Thanks Ken. I ran the regedit in administrator mode and tried modifying that key but it still doesn't allow me to change that key. The error says: "Cannot edit: error writing the value's new contents". Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, no. It appears you *do* have some AV or malware prevention software, or you have other issues with your system. However, for the *third* time, this is not a programming question and is off topic here. We're now in the area of general computer support (not even software installation). Ask a question at [su] about this issue and how to solve it. :-)

Comment: See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation for a discussion of some of these issues.

Comment: @Ken I understand this. I just saw some other related posts about issues with Postgresql installation so I posted here in SO. But will move to SuperUser afterwards.

Comment: Those are most likely from before [su] existed, and at the time they were posted they were on topic here. Things change. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite You should take a look at the answer I posted for the question [he asked on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/601505/why-cant-i-change-window-7-registry-key). That regestery key by default can't be written, even by an administrator.

Comment: @Scott: Yep, right you are. I didn't look that closely at anything past the `HKLM`.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/take-full-permissions-control-edit-protected-registry-keys/) link, and you can change the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Classes->CLSID->B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8} -> InprocServer32`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing in my registry setting. I do know that I had McAfee installed for our enterprise.

Instead of trying to change the registry value I was able to click on the McAfee icon, Quick Settings, turn OFF both Host IPS and Network IPS (probably just could have turned off the Host IPS.)

This let the installer run. I then turned them back on.